# LocalStorage, JavaScript and Objects

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I need to store an object in localStorage - and I know that in order to do so, I have to convert the object into a string. All cool.

My problem is in actually creating the object in the first place: I have two values in sessionStorage that need to be added to the object which is then passed into localStorage. However, when I try to create the object, one value is being stored as the variable name rather than its (numeric) value. Any idea whats going on here?

```
var siteName = sessionStorage['1'];
var siteID = (+sessionStorage['2']);
var temp = {siteID:siteName};
alert(typeof siteID);
alert(JSON.stringify(temp));
```

The first alert confirms  that siteID is indeed a number type, but the second alert shows that the variable name (siteID) is stored rather than its numeric value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
var temp = {siteID:siteName};
```

...creates an object containing a property called `siteId` with the value taken from the `siteName` variable.

If you want the property name to be taken from the `siteID` variable instead:

```
var temp = {};
temp[siteID] = siteName;
```

Or in ES2015 (aka "ES6") you could use the new *computed property name* syntax:

```
// ES2015+ only!
var temp = {[siteId]: siteName};
```

In JavaScript, you can access/create properties on objects in two different but equal ways: Using dotted notation with a literal property name:

```
obj.foo = "bar";    // Creates a `foo` property on `obj` with the value `"bar"`
```

...or using bracketed notation and a string:

```
obj["foo"] = "bar"; // Does the same thing
```

The keys in object initializers like your `var temp = {siteID:siteName};` are always used literally (although they can optionally be in quotes); there's no way with an object initializer to have a key taken from a variable instead. So you have to do it as a two-step process, first create the object, then set the property.

So, if you do

```
temp[siteID] = siteName;
```

...the number in `siteID` will be converted to a string and will become the property name, with the value of `siteName` being the value.

```
var temp = {};
var key = 1;
temp[key] = "value";
console.log(temp[1]); // "value"
console.log(temp["1"]); // "value"
```

(Property names are always strings in JavaScript [for now].)

Comment: Also thanks for the explanation (saw your enedited version first ;) ) -  clearly explained what 3 useless tutorials couldn't!

Comment: @Squishy: That's great to hear!

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this.

```
var temp = {};

temp[siteName] = siteID;
```

Or if the `typeof` test was meant to show the property name, you'd reverse them.

```
var temp = {};

temp[siteID] = siteName;
```

But be aware that `siteID` is considered a String from that point forward.

Comment: I think you have the key/value backwards

Comment: @Mathletics: Yes, you're right. I was confused by the `typeof` test, thinking that was meant to be the value. I'll update. Thanks for the hint.